# How to use dynamic request body for HTTP Request plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, httprequest, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I can able to hit the end point URL along with request body for POST method. But I just want to know how can I use different data in JSON request body to hit the same end point URL that mentioned in the HTTP Request Jenkins plugin.

Sample JSON request body:

```
{
  "duration": "2019-02-10T08:08:12.300Z",
  "domain": "Google Pay",
  "priority": "1",
  "flowId": 022,
  "subFlowId": 110,
  "productId": 180
}
```

For that above request body I just want to change the "subFlowId" value for single build. Like The above request JSON file need to hit the end point with different values.

I have a list of payloads which is available in workspace, and just want to pass those JSON (above is reference) content as request body in HTTP Request plugin.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's a bit broad question. What this JSON comes from? Do you map it to an object and back?

Comment: This is request json file which is going to be income payload for endPoint. Similar that I have same payload only the subFlowId will change and that is available in ${workspace}. I just need to read the JSON payload that's available on workspace and applied into the Request body.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def myJson = '{"subFlowId":"1.0.0"}'
def myObject = JsonOutput.toJson(myJson)
myObject.subFlowId = 'something cool'
//back to string
myJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(myObject)
```

Comment: Where can i use this groovy in http request? will it work if i use it as request body?

Comment: How do you use it now?

Comment: I'm just using the above json as request body in HTTP Request plugin. If I build it once it will run with one payload and complete the execution with 200 response back. I wanna do the same with all the payload which is relay on the workspace for single build.

Comment: Please update your question with your current code so this can be properly answered.